# I'm trying to use socket.io with nextjs but my code is getting executed twice

Tags: next.js, socket.io, next.js13

So I'm using socket.io with nextjs and express as the backend when I'm either trying to connect to my server or emit and event everything is firing twice

I even tried adding if (typeof window !== 'undefined') but it's still firing twice

```js
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";
import { fetchUserInfo } from "@/utils/fetchUserInfo";
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import getSocket from "@/components/getSocket";
config({path: '../.env.development.local'})
 
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const { cookie } = context.req.headers;
 
    if (context.req.cookies['gameStatus'] === undefined){
        return{
            notFound: true
        }
    }
    else{
        const {displayName, userAvatar, isCookieAvailable}  = await fetchUserInfo(cookie)
 
        return{
            props: {
                displayName, userAvatar, isCookieAvailable
            }
        }
    }
}
 
export default function Game({displayName, userAvatar, isCookieAvailable}){
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        const socket = io(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL)
        console.log('here')
        socket.emit('event', 'eventlog')
    }
 
    return(
        <>
            <Navbar displayName={displayName} userAvatar={userAvatar} isCookieAvailable={isCookieAvailable}/> :
            {!isCookieAvailable && <div style={{color: 'white'}}>Not logged in please login</div>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself after a few days and the reason turns out to be strict mode. If you turn it off it works perfect without any problems:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode